# Global Counter In Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having a problem making my counter work in my recursion, instead of printing 11, it prints 11,1s. where am I making a mistake?

```
def power(x, n):
    global countcalls # note countcalls variable is in my global and it is equal to 0 
    countcalls = +1
    print(countcalls)
    if n <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * power(x, n-1)
```

my output:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1024
```

output wanted :

```
11
1024
```

Comment: `countcalls = +1` should be `countcalls += 1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, `countcalls = +1` doesn't increment the variable, it just sets it to `1`. To increment, use `+= 1`, not `= +1`.

Second, if you only want to print at the end, put the `print()` call in the base case.

Instead of using a global variable, use another parameter that defaults to `0`.

```
def power(x, n, countcalls = 0):
    countcalls += 1
    if n <= 0:
        print(countcalls)
        return 1
    else:
        return x * power(x, n-1, countcalls)
```